# package not exist в Android Studio

Tags: android

В учебнике по андроид разработке, по которому я учусь, указано использовать эти библиотеки

```
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v4.content.res.ResourcesCompat;
import android.support.v7.widget.CardView;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
```

Для того,чтобы их добавить в build.gradle я добавила следующие строки

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.6'
```

В учебном проекте это работает, но в моём почему-то эти библиотеки не находятся. Ошибки по типу error: `package android.support.design.widget does not exist`

Подскажите, в чем дело. Спасибо

Comment: учебник устарел, используйте AndroidX библиотеки

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Support` библиотеки уже давненько устарели и не используются.

`AndroidX` заменяет оригинальные `API` библиотеки поддержки пакетами в пространстве имен `androidx`. Изменены только имена пакетов и артефактов `Maven`. Имена классов, методов и полей не изменились.

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.0'
```

Более подробно стоит почитать в [документации](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate), а так же [здесь.](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx)

Comment: Отлично, это сработало. Спасибо!